Proof verification for translation is continuous in $L^1$
We want to show that the translation with respect to $t$ is continuous for $L^1$ functions. Specifically, it suffices to show that $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x + t) - f(x)| \, \mathrm d m = 0$$
Where $m$ is the lebesgue measure and $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.
My proof is as follows:
We know that $$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x + t) - f(x) | \, \mathrm dm = 0 \iff \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x + t)|\, \mathrm dm  = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|\, \mathrm dm$$
This is abuse of notation but I believe its well known with sequences of functions $|f_k - f|_{L^1} \to 0 \iff |f_k|_{L^1} \to |f|_{L^1}$ but you can take any sequence of $t \to 0$ for this part.
By change of variables with $y = x + t$, and $y' = 1$ we get: $$ \lim_{t \to 0}\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x + t)| \, \mathrm d m = \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(y)| \, \mathrm dm(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, \mathrm dm $$
And thus we are done. $\square$
I submitted this for homework a few weeks ago, but I got no substantial feedback from the TA. Is there a mistake in my proof, specifically around the change of variables part? The proof my professor gave in the solutions was longer, and relies on $C_c$ being compact in $L^1$, so I wasn't sure if I had made a mistake.

Your first equivalence is not clear.

@copper.hat The problem statement of the first equivalence in the proof?

The iff after "We know that
".

You can prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n - f|{L^p} = 0 \iff \lim{n \to \infty} |f_n|{L^p} = |f|{L^p}$ for $0 < p < \infty$ and any sequence of functions $f_n \in L^p$. Since limits are just sequences, we can set $t_k \to 0$, and then $f_k = f(x + t_k)$, and you would have the original statement I believe

The $\implies$ is straightforward, the other direction is not true. As a trivial example, in general $f \neq -f$ but $|f| = |-f|$.

thank you! The condition I forgot about was $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere.

You might want to clarify that in your equivalence :-).

To close this post, thanks to copper.hat the mistake is in the line:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x + t) - f(x)| \, \mathrm d m = 0 \iff \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x + t)| \, \mathrm d m = \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| \, \mathrm d m$$
As this holds under the additional hypothesis $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere. Since we are $L^1$, the function is not necessarily continuous and thus we can't apply it.
